# getting X,Y while dragging in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I get precise X,Y coordinates while dragging ?

I used onDragListener but it gave me X,Y on the screen and this doesn't work for me .

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by the screen x/y coordinates don't work? What frame of reference are you looking for for x/y?

Comment: well I tried to drop an object on a frame layout ...when the DragEvent.ACTION_DROP is fired I used event.getX() ..I want the X,Y over the frame layout (the drag-zone) not X,Y on the screen :\ @munch1324

Comment: Do you know the frame layout that this is occurring inside of? If so, can you just subtract the X/Y coordinate of the frame layout to get the local x / y?

Comment: It is done ...it is giving me coordinates with around 25 px offset